# Bootstrap modal stop scrolling on Chrome 41 with mouse scroll/touchpad (but works with up/down keys)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

My objective is to get a scrollable bootstrap modal that is taller than my screen.

**Problem**: 
On Chrome 41 (but not 40) running on Yosemite OS, my bootstrap modal would stop scrolling after it pops up if the content height is taller than the screen.

**What I have tried is**: 
- Straight Bootstrap(v.3.3.1) automatically adds '.modal-open' to the body tag with the property of 'overflow: hidden;'. This causes the modal to be scrollable.
- I adjusted the widow size and just by moving a pixel, the modal is scrollable again.
- I have tried applying overflow: visible; and etc. to both the body tag and the modal itself but no luck.

Does anyone know what this problem is? Is it a bug Chrome 41 introduced on Yosemite? I am using Bootstrap 3.3.1 currently.

**Updated** scrolling with up/down arrow keys work fine but not with mouse/touchpad scrolling.

Comment: I doubt it is OS related. Probably a slight difference between how Chrome 40 and 41 interpret the CSS. Can you post your code?

Comment: @snowYetis It happens every time on bootstrap modal when the content is taller than the screen. My code is just a simple $('#selector').modal('show') on a button click event. It only happens on Chrome 41.

Comment: Check the bootstrap modal styles. See if any contain overflow:hidden

Comment: the modal itself has a overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: auto property, which makes sense. I even tried overflow-y: visible and scroll too. If I apply it again within chrome inspector, it will work again. But it won't work if I apply it thorough css file. It is not being clobbered by other styles (I checked).

Comment: Ya that's weird. Try adding a z-index to the style property that contains the overflow attributes. It's a shot in the dark but maybe the scroll bar is being covered by a different piece.

Comment: sounds very plausible. I'll keep digging and reply.

Comment: it does scroll with up/down keys. so you are definitely right. Something's up with the scroll. Going to update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issue. After quick search I found that someone already reported this on [their GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16297) and there is actual fix that was proposed about six days ago, but it hasn't been accepted yet, which means it's not in any stable version right now.

You can apply the proposed fix in your css easily:

```
.modal.in {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well on Windows - chrome 44.0.2403.  It looks like this is a known issue with Chrome that the bootstrap devs won't fix due to other issues with translateZ: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16297

Comment: This solved the scroll problem of Angual-UI (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal in chrome. Firefox works fine.

Comment: Best solution Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Win7 Chrome 41 and 42beta & Linux Chrome 41.
My temporary solution: set viewport height + 1px to page by js to have scrollbar active every time.

Comment: Ah I see. Good to know that it's not just happening to me. Awesome! My temporary solution is to set wrap the cotent insided the modal in a div and setting the overflow-y: scroll so it is scrollable inside the modal.